# Should I say "to another" or "to another one"?

Tags: definition

What's the difference between these two expressions?

For example, I want to say

> you can also assign a job to another
>   you can also assign a job to another **one**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both examples convey the same meaning and are grammatical.

> You can also assign a job to another.

Here,  **another** is used as a pronoun.

> You can also assign a job to another one.

Here **another** is used as an adjective that modifies the pronoun **one**.